# Exception при вызове onDestroy() Android

Tags: activity

Имеется приложение-викторина. Как только у пользователя заканчиваются "жизни", его нужно переместить в новое активити результатов, а старое (с вопросами) удалить, чтобы он потом не смог нажать кнопку "назад" и продолжить играть. Я вызываю метод `onDestroy()`, активити удаляется, но при этом поверх приложения вылазит окно с ошибкой "В приложении "таком-то" произошла ошибка.". После чего я нажимаю "ОК" и приложение работает дальше правильно. Как убрать эту всплывающую ошибку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onDestroy` не нужно вызывать самостоятельно. Нужно вызывать `finish`, причем, из UI-потока (UI thread).